# send post with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, http-post

hi guys i been trying to send a post value using ajax
this is my pages:

I have a page that is the modal modal_image.php with this code:

```
var image;
function addImage() {
    $.ajax({
        url:'registration.php',
        data:{image:document.getElementById('output').src},
        type:'POST',
        success:function (data){
            if(!data.error){
                document.getElementById('userImage').src=document.getElementById('output').src;
                image=document.getElementById('userImage').src;
                $("#try").text(image);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and this my registration.php page:

```
<p><?php echo $_POST['image'];?></p>
<p id="try"></p>
```

i have showed u a limit of the code...

when I open the modal and upload the photos the 'p' element with the id=try is working and I can see the image src

but the first p with the post value I see an error

[image: the image that show the error]

Comment: `registration.php` is same page from where `addImage()` gets called ? If yes onload that value will be empty so add isset condtion around your `p`  tag.

Comment: That error seem to be unrelated to that javascript code, since it doesn't output the response for you rajax call. You won't be able to use `data.error` unless the page you're calling returns json, which it doesn't (since it returns HTML)

Comment: no addImage is the button in the modal

Comment: What should be the output in <?php echo $_POST['image'];?>? Do you like to see the Image or what?

Comment: What do you get if you only output `$_POST` in your registration.php ? The error is quite clear the index "image" in the array "$_POST" does not exist

Comment: the POST array is somehow empty, although I send with ajax the PHP variable

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Are you trying to Upload a new image or just pass in a URL for an existing image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following code.

```js
function addImage(source) {
  $.post('registration.php', {
    image: source
  }, function(data) {
    if (!data.error) {
      $('#userImage').attr("src", source);
      $("#try").text($('#userImage').attr("src"));
    }
  });
}

addImage($("#output").attr("src"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="output" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/ccc/fff.png&text=TEST" />
<p id="try"></p>
```

You can pass in the URL String that you want to Add into your Function. This way, it can be a bit more dynamic and you now have the data easily available to the whole function.